# Setting returnurl in payflow pro secure token request

Tags: paypal, payflowpro, returnurl

I'm trying to implement Payflow Pro's transparent redirect in multiple locations on a site. The main purchase page has been set up and uses the returnurl, errorurl, silentposturl values set up in the PayPal Manager account.  However, I would really like to set up different return urls for the other areas of the site where transactions also occur.

I'm know that the secure token requests allow you to set values for return, error, cancel and silentpost urls that will override the Manager account settings, but I can't seem to make that work.

Our secure token requests use php/cURL and I'm able to successfully request a token and use it in a test transaction but still get redirected back to the return url defined in the Manager account instead of the one I define in my secure token request. I thought if I was getting a successful response back from the gateway along with a token that everything was good to go.  This is what is passed in for the secure token request:

```
SILENTTRAN=TRUE&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&CURRENCY=USD&TRXTYPE=S&SECURETOKENID=XXXX&AMT=10.00&RETURNURL=https://site.com/returnurl.php&CANCELURL=https://site.com/cancelurl.php&ERRORURL=https://site.com/errorurl.php&SILENTPOSTURL=https://site.com/silentposturl.php
```

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction about where I could be going wrong or what could be the causing the gateway not to recognize my return url values?

Answer (score 4):

For people still struggling with this, what ultimately worked for me was to make sure I was passing ReturnURL, ErrorURL, and CancelURL during the Secure Token call (not during the payment call):   Here is the entire contents of my Secure Token call:

```
PARTNER=PayPal
&VENDOR=testpayflow
&USER=testpayflow
&PWD=testpass
&TRXTYPE=S
&TENDER=C
&VERBOSITY=MEDIUM
&COMMENT1=MY-COMMENT
&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=John
&BILLTOLASTNAME=Doe
&BILLTOSTREET=101 E. Elm St.
&BILLTOSTREET2=
&BILLTOCITY=Denver
&BILLTOSTATE=CO
&BILLTOZIP=80211
&BILLTOCOUNTRY=840
&BILLTOPHONENUM=303-333-3333
&CURRENCY=USD
&AMT=55
&EMAIL=testemail@test.com
&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y
&RETURNURL=https://example.com/cart/PayflowReturn
&ERRORURL=https://example.com/cart/PayflowReturn
&CANCELURL=https://example.com/cart
&SECURETOKENID=0015d2a274ebb7b70e71556c4c95a64c
&SILENTTRAN=TRUE
```

Comment: You just saved me from an ENORMOUS headache. Thank you, thank you, thank you! No where in the PayPal docs does it **explicitly** say that you have to pass in these params when making the token- just when you send the POST data to the hosted page.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to create a secure token. You then pass the secure token with the hosted pages configuration parameters.(in this case, your error, cancel, and silent post URLs).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I'm understanding your instructions properly, I've pass in my values for the error/cancel/return/silentpost urls in my secure token request. I'm then given the secure token, response message of 'approved' and a result of '0'.  However, when I then apply the secure token, secure token id, and other transaction parameters to the actual credit card form and go through the transparent redirect process, I'm still being redirected to the return url set in my Manager Account.  Should I be setting the desired return url elsewhere as well?

Comment: leave your urls out of the secure token request altogether. Here's an example:TRXTYPE=A&BILLTOSTREET=123 Main St.&BILLTOZIP=95131&AMT=23.45&CURRENCY=USD&INVNUM=INV12345&PONUM=PO9876&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4c5

Comment: then use the secure token and token ID you receive to call the URL parameters along with your card data (above example missing SILENTTRANS=Y

Comment: I've corrected my secure token request to be:


SILENTTRAN=TRUE&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&CURRENCY=USD&TRXTYPE=S&SECURETOKENID=1399439411d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ec&AMT=10.00


And then moved the url parameters over to my card form submit step.  although my transactions seem to be going through perfectly and showing up as sales in the list for test transactions in my manager account, I'm still unable to redirect to the return url I specified in the form. I'm truly at a loss on where I'm going off course

Comment: I re-read the documentation and my original statement was incorrect; your return, error and silent post URLs should be specified in the secure token request. If you post your secure token request here I can test it (strip out your credentials), however, because you are obtaining a secure token I do not think your issue has anything to do with coding. Another thing you might consider is filing a ticket with PayPal Merchant Technical Services.

Comment: Thank you again for your advice! I followed your instructions and put the URLs in to my secure token request and also reached out to Merchant Technical Services for anything else I could be overlooking.  After a lot of back and forth and frustrating results, I found out a totally different function in my file was causing a 302 redirect header, which caused me to be booted out to the error url.  I'm still not sure why I'm still getting taken to the default error url, but I'm really happy that I'm now being redirected to the proper returnurl for all my post transaction processing.